# Largest Contentful Paint element 3,150 ms, how to reduce?

Tags: mobile-website, web-testing

How can I reduce the time to largest contentful paint?
[image: how to reduce?]

In my PageSpeed Insights I'm getting this message, LCP over 3s for mobile devices. Desktop is like 1-2s, so is ok. I reduced all my image sizes, because they were causing the LCP over 3s at first, and now the problem is the first paragraph section.

So this is what I tried:
WP Rocket:

- Enable caching for mobile devices
- Minify CSS
- Optimize CSS delivery (Remove Unused CSS)
- Minify JavaScript
- Load JavaScript deferred
- Enable Lazy load for images and CSS background images
- Activate Preload
- Cloudflare Add-on is currently enabled. Configuration CDN

I also noticed the long Network request time which is almost 1s. So I really don't know what else to do. Can someone help me out here?
[image]